# Determining the mode of a list

Tags: python, statsmodels

So through this program I'm doing for an assignment, I've gotten correctly the count, mean, and median of this list. I don't know how to get the mode correctly for this problem. But unfortunately I keep getting a 'unhashable type:'list'' Any help with the mode?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class StatsList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
        self.nums = []

    def append(self, number):
        self.nums.append(number)

    def count(self):
        count = len(self.nums)
        return count

    def mean(self):
        for num in self.nums:
            self.sum = self.sum + num

        return self.sum /len(self.nums)

    def median(self):
        self.nums.sort()
        midPos = self.count() // 2

        if self.count() % 2 == 0:
            median = (nums[midPos] + nums[midPos-1]) / 2.0
        else:
            median = self.nums[midPos]

        return median

    def mode(self):
        counts= {}
        for num in self.nums:
            counts[num] = counts.get(self.nums,0) + 1
        items = list(counts.nums())
        self.nums.sort(key=byFreq)

def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def main():
    l = StatsList()
    l.append(1)
    l.append(11)
    l.append(3)
    l.append(1)
    l.append(4)

    print("Count:", l.count()) # should print 5
    print("Mean:", l.mean()) # should print 4.0
    print("Median:", l.median()) # should print 3
    print("Mode:", l.mode()) # should print 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output/traceback:

```
Count: 5
Mean: 4.0
Median: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dorthyy\Downloads\statslist.py", line 63, in <module>
     main()
  File "C:\Users\Dorthyy\Downloads\statslist.py", line 59, in main
print("Mode:", l.mode()) # should print 1
  File "C:\Users\Dorthyy\Downloads\statslist.py", line 39, in mode
    counts[num] = counts.get(self.nums,0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
 >>>
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've included it

Answer (score 2):

`self.nums` is the `list` that stores all the numbers. You can't `get()` that from a dictionary because `list` can't be used as a dictionary key. You need the actual number that you're getting from the loop iteration. Instead of `counts.get(self.nums, 0)`, use `counts.get(num, 0)`.

This should fix the rest of the errors in that method:

```
def mode(self):
    counts= {}
    for num in self.nums:
        counts[num] = counts.get(num, 0) + 1
    mode = max(counts, key=counts.get)
    return '{} appeared {} times'.format(mode, counts[mode])
```

The mode is just the key with the maximum value, so it's clearer to get the `max()` of that dictionary, by value (this means you don't need the `byFreq` method at all). Then you return a nicely-formatted string with the mode and the number of times it appeared.

Comment: for some reason I'm still getting an error that says 'dict' object has no attribute 'num'

Comment: Try `items()` instead of `nums()`.

Comment: Now I got the mode, but it's telling me that there is no mode. When the mode is supposed to be 1.

Comment: What do you mean, you got a mode but there's no mode?

Comment: The output for mode says 'None'

Comment: Well, maybe you should `return` something. `return items`, for example.

Comment: When I return items though it gives me a list of the numbers and how many times it has occurred. But, it doesn't show how many 1s have occur ed.

Comment: @Dorthy - I cleaned up the `mode()` method; see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing counts as a dictionary and trying to assign a LIST as a key to that dictionary. self.nums is a list. that's why you are getting

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

try this code.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def mode(self):
    counts= OrderedDict()
    for num in self.nums:
        counts[num] = counts.get(num,0) + 1
    return counts.items()[0][0]
```

take note that here I am initializing counts as OrderedDict() which will store elements in sorted manner so after the for loop you just need to return first element of the ordereddict. and inside for loop I am assigning single elements from self.nums as key to that ordereddict.
hope it helps.

on the side note. if you want to get `4.0` as answer to `l.mean()` you need to multiply the return value by `1.0` before returning it.